# Access Map<String,Map<String,Integer> in Visualforce without repeat tag

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to access a `Map<String,Map<String,Integer>`  in VF but I dont want to use repeat tag, as I know we can access a `Map<String,String>` as {!MapVal['Key']} in a page without any error.

but for the `Map<String,Map<String,Integer>`  when I do this {!MapVal['Key']} it through a error as value not found in map. But at lest I should get the inside Map!!

Any Help!!

```
   <apex:page controller="JqueryDragDropController" id="pageId" showHeader="false">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
    $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    var count = 0;
    var drArray = null ;
    $j(document).ready(function() {  
        drArray = $j( "[Id*='06690000003mytx:draggableMaster']" );
        drArray.draggable();
        callAction();
        var cursorAt = drArray.draggable( {
            start: function(event,ui) {
                var drbutton = $j( "[Id*='droppossition']" );
                drbutton.text("");
            },
            stop: function(event,ui) {
                var drbutton = $j( "[Id*='droppossition']" );
                drbutton.text("top:"+ui.position.top+" left:"+ui.position.left);
                callAction();
            }
            });

    });

    function revertAll(){
        // setter

        if(count == 0){
            drArray.draggable( "option", "revert", true);
            count = 1;
        }
        else{
            drArray.draggable( "option", "revert", false);
            count = 0;
        }
    }

    function callAction(){
        var valuesF = "";
        for(i = 0; i < drArray.length; i++){
            var offset = drArray.eq(i).offset();
            valuesF += drArray[i].id+","+offset.left+","+offset.top+";";
        }
        echo(valuesF);
    }

</script>
<style>
    .divDragBody{
        color:black;
        background-color:red;
        height:150px;
        width:150px;
        text-align:center;
        border-style:solid;
        float:left;
        margin:0px 0px 0px 20px;
        z-index:2;
    }

    .divDragChild{
        color:black;
        background-color:white;
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
        text-align:center;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        border-style:solid;
        z-index:4;
    }
    #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
</style>

<apex:form id="formId">
    <apex:actionFunction name="echo" action="{!echoVal}" reRender="formId" >
        <apex:param name="JQIDPossition" assignTo="{!pageJQIdPoss}" value="" />
    </apex:actionFunction>

    <apex:repeat value="{!CurrentJQPoss}" var="in">
        {!in}<br></br>
        <apex:outputText value="{!CurrentJQPoss[in].Top}"/><br></br>
        <apex:outputText value="{!CurrentJQPoss[in].Left}"/><br></br>
    </apex:repeat>
 <apex:outputText value="{!CurrentJQPoss['06690000003mytx:draggableMaster1']['Left']}"/>
</apex:form>
    <button type="button" onclick="revertAll()">Revert</button>  

    <div id="{!JQElementId[0]}" class="divDragBody" style="left:0px;top:0px;">
      Drag Element 1 
    </div> 

    <div id="{!JQElementId[1]}" class="divDragBody">
      Drag Element 2 {!mpStr['11']}
    </div>
    <div id="droppossition">
    </div> 


</apex:page>
```

controller:

```
    global with sharing class JqueryDragDropController {
    public Map<String,JqueryDragDrop_PointSave__c> JQPossition {get;set;}
    public Map<String,Map<String,Integer>> CurrentJQPoss{get;set;}
    public Map<String,String> mpStr {get;set;}
    public List<String> JQElementId{get;set;}
    public Id SFDCId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
    public String preIdCode{get;set;}
    public String pageJQIdPoss{get;set;}

    public JqueryDragDropController (){
        JQPossition = new Map<String,JqueryDragDrop_PointSave__c> ();
        CurrentJQPoss = new Map<String,Map<String,Integer>> ();
        mpStr = new Map<String,String> ();
        mpStr.put('11','***eleven');
        preIdCode = '06690000003mytx';
        JQElementId = new List<String>();
        JQElementId.add(preIdCode+':draggableMaster1');
        JQElementId.add(preIdCode+':draggableMaster2');
    }

    public void fillJQPossiotion(){
        JQPossition = JqueryDragDrop_PointSave__c.getAll();

            List<JqueryDragDrop_PointSave__c > JQPLstInsert = new List<JqueryDragDrop_PointSave__c >();
            List<JqueryDragDrop_PointSave__c > JQPLstUpdate = new List<JqueryDragDrop_PointSave__c >();

            for(String str: JQElementId){
                if(JQPossition.containsKey(str) == false){
                    JqueryDragDrop_PointSave__c jqp = new JqueryDragDrop_PointSave__c();
                    jqp.Name = str;
                    jqp.Element_Left__c = string.valueof(CurrentJQPoss.get(str).get('Left'));
                    jqp.Element_Top__c = string.valueof(CurrentJQPoss.get(str).get('Top'));
                    JQPLstInsert.add(jqp);
                }
                else{
                    JqueryDragDrop_PointSave__c jqp = new JqueryDragDrop_PointSave__c();
                    jqp = JQPossition.get(str);
                    jqp.Element_Left__c = string.valueof(CurrentJQPoss.get(str).get('Left'));
                    jqp.Element_Top__c = string.valueof(CurrentJQPoss.get(str).get('Top'));
                    JQPLstUpdate.add(jqp);
                }
            }
            if(!JQPLstInsert.isEmpty()){
                insert JQPLstInsert ;
            }    
            else if(!JQPLstUpdate.isEmpty()){
                system.debug('***update'+JQPLstUpdate);
                update JQPLstUpdate;
            }

    }

    public void echoVal(){
        system.debug('***pageJQIdPoss**'+pageJQIdPoss);
        String subStr = '';
        for(Integer i=0;pageJQIdPoss!='';i++){
            subStr = pageJQIdPoss.substring(0,pageJQIdPoss.indexOf(';')+1);
            system.debug('***subStr **'+subStr );
            string subStrId = subStr.substring(0,subStr.indexOf(','));
            system.debug('***subStrId **'+subStrId );
            String subStrTop = subStr.substring(subStr.indexOf(',')+1,subStr.lastindexOf(','));
            system.debug('***subStrTop **'+subStrTop );
            String subStrLeft = subStr.substring(subStr.lastindexOf(',')+1,subStr.indexOf(';'));
            system.debug('***subStrLeft **'+subStrLeft );
            Map<String,Integer> mp = new Map<String,Integer>();
            mp.put('Left',Integer.valueof(subStrLeft) );
            mp.put('Top',Integer.valueof(subStrTop) );
            CurrentJQPoss.put(subStrId ,mp);
            pageJQIdPoss = pageJQIdPoss.remove(subStr); 
            system.debug('***CurrentJQPoss**'+CurrentJQPoss);

        }
        fillJQPossiotion();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post a code sample showing your problem given that Martin's answer is not working for you.

Comment: @MikeChale i have updated the code here..

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
 {!MapVal['Key']['KeyMapB']}
```

Complete sample:

Apex

```
   Map<String,Integer> x = new Map<String,Integer>();
    x.put('b',3);

    Map<String,Map<String,Integer>> m = new Map<String,Map<String,Integer>>();
    m.put('a',x);
```

VF

```
   {!m['a']['b']} >>> this will show 3
```

Comment: hi i tried as {!CurrentJQPoss['06690000003mytx']['Top'] but it gives error as "Map key 06690000003mytx not found in map" but the value is there.

Comment: Are you sure that the key 06690000003mytx exists?, because the error is saying that the problem is in the key of the first map, not the second one. Try first something simpler (map filled by constants)

Comment: the map is actually filled with constants  the values are displaying on page as: {06690000003mytx:draggableMaster1={Left=15, Top=20}, 06690000003mytx:draggableMaster2={Left=15, Top=196}} this is the map values and i am doing this :  {!CurrentJQPoss['06690000003mytx:draggableMaster1']['Left']}

Comment: yes I have done that but nothing same error, se my above comment

Comment: I've updated my answer using a simple example that is working.

Comment: sry same result !!

Comment: could you paste your entire code?

Comment: I think that you have an order problem. You are setting the map after you are trying to render it. Please, make a new page setting the map on the controller constructor.